# Add swipeGesture to webView and stop ZoomIn and ZoomOut

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I need to add `swipeGesture` to my `UIWebView`, however I need to stop the ZoomIn and ZoomOut of that `UIWebView`

```
/*Swipe is enabled and zoom as well*/
    webViewPlayer.scalesPageToFit = true
```

When I am changing it to

```
webViewPlayer.scalesPageToFit = false
//zooming and swipe both disabled
```

**Edit 1**

I just want swipeGesture to `UIWebView` only without `ZoomIn` and `ZoomOut`

I have tried adding `swipeGesture` to both `UIWebView` and `self.view`

Comment: check my improved answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Because `UIWebView` contains `scrollview` in it so you can use method below to check that scroll is on which direction.

This is an alternative way to check direction of Swipe because swipe gesture don't work on very well `UIWebView`.

Give `scrollviewDelegate` to `UIWebView`

```
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

**ScrollView Delegate**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    if velocity.x < 0
    {
        print("Going Left!")
    }
    else if velocity.x > 1
    {
        print("Going Right!")
    }
}
```

Comment: check my improved answer.